# React Render Components with Array.map auto scrolls down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I have a ProjectsSection component in React and an array of project objects. Initially it renders just the first 3 projects. I also have a button which when its clicked all other objects are rendered too.

```
const showMoreProjects = () => {
    if (projectsToShow === 3) {
      setProjectsToShow(projects.length)
      showBtn.current.innerHTML = 'show less'
    } else {
      setProjectsToShow(3)
      showBtn.current.innerHTML = 'show more'
    }
  }

<div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
{
    projects.slice(0, projectsToShow).map(project => <Project key={project.title} details={project} />)
}
</div>

<button ref={showBtn} onClick={showMoreProjects}>view more</button>
```

Here is the Project component

```
<div ref={project} className="project relative w-full h-64 bg-gray-800 rounded-lg bg-cover bg-center overflow-hidden"
      style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${details.imgUrl})` }}>
      <div className="w-full h-full flex justify-center items-center">
        <div className="project-card-hover opacity-0 hover:opacity-100 transition-opacity duration-300 ease-in-out w-full h-full">
          <div className="w-full h-full flex flex-col justify-center items-center bg-black bg-opacity-50">
            <h1 className="text-4xl text-white mb-8">{details.title}</h1>
            <div className="w-1/2 flex justify-around items-center text-white text-2xl">
              <a href={details.link} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLink} /></a>
              <a href={details.github} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGithub} /></a>
              <a href={details.play} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlay} /></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When more projects are shown, browser auto scrolls down to the last components rendered! Can that be prevented?

Comment: Nothing here should be causing a scroll. Are you sure there's not something in your `Project` component that you need to share?

Comment: I updated the question, I think it happens because it focuses on the button that i press or something!

Comment: Ah yes, that could be it. There's a way around that.

Comment: The only thing I could think of is use scrollIntoView to the start of the PorjectSection, but seems like bad design to me. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of a button when there's a mouse down event is to give it focus. This may be causing the scrolling behavior as you supposed. To avoid this default behavior, you can place your event handler on the `mousedown` event instead of `click` and call the event's `preventDefault` method:

```
const showMoreProjects = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (projectsToShow === 3) {
    setProjectsToShow(projects.length)
    showBtn.current.innerHTML = 'show less'
  } else {
    setProjectsToShow(3)
    showBtn.current.innerHTML = 'show more'
  }
}

// ...

<button ref={showBtn} onMouseDown={showMoreProjects}>view more</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it! Both the preventDefault and the onMouseDown instead of the onClick that I used!